# How to spy on node module function with vitest (typescript)

Tags: typescript, testing, node-modules, vitest

I am trying to test a TypeScript function which calls a library function (https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-js-sdk to be specific). My addPoll() function takes some values and sets the parameters of a matrix message event, then calls the sendEvent() function of the Matrix protocol. The Matrix sendEvent() function then sends a message event to the current room with the values given from my addPoll() function. To be able to test my function with vitest, I also need to mock or spy on this Matrix function.

I have read the mocking documentation of vitest and specifically the part regarding third-party modules (https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#modules). However, the documentation doesn't really help me with my issue and I couldn't find an answer anywhere else.

This is the test.ts file:

```
import {beforeEach, describe, expect, test, vi} from 'vitest';
import { usePubHubs } from '@/core/pubhubsStore.ts';
import { createClient } from "matrix-js-sdk";
import { VotingWidgetType, PollVotingType } from '@/types/events';
import {createPinia, setActivePinia} from "pinia";

describe('poll message', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        setActivePinia(createPinia());
    });

    test('addPoll', () => {
        // Create a spy for addPoll and sendEvent
        const client = createClient({ baseUrl: "https://matrix.org" });

        const addPollSpy = vi.spyOn(usePubHubs(), 'addPoll');
        const sendEventSpy = vi.spyOn(client, 'sendEvent');

        const roomId = 'roomId';
        const title = 'Favorite Color Poll';
        const description = 'What is your favorite color?';
        const options = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'];
        const widgetType = VotingWidgetType.POLL;
        const votingType = PollVotingType.RADIO;

        usePubHubs().addPoll(roomId, title, description, options, widgetType, votingType);

        // Expect addPoll to be called with specific parameters
        expect(addPollSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(roomId, title, description, options, widgetType, votingType);

        // Expect sendEvent to be called with specific parameters
        expect(sendEventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(roomId, 'm.room.message', {
            msgtype: 'm.voting_widget',
            body: title,
            title: title,
            description: description,
            options: options,
            type: widgetType,
            voting_type: votingType
        });
    })
});
```

Here's the implementation of addPoll() function for clarity:

```
async addPoll(roomId: string, title: string, description: string, options: Array<M_PollMessageOptions>, widget_type: VotingWidgetType, voting_type: PollVotingType = PollVotingType.RADIO) {
            const content = {
                msgtype: 'm.voting_widget',
                body: title,
                title: title,
                description: description,
                options: options,
                type: widget_type,
                voting_type: voting_type,
            };
            await this.client.sendEvent(roomId, 'm.room.message', content);
        },
```

And this is the error I am getting when I run the `npm test` command:

```
TypeError: this.client.sendEvent is not a function
 ❯ Proxy.addPoll src/core/pubhubsStore.ts:298:22
    296|     voting_type: voting_type,
    297|    };
    298|    await this.client.sendEvent(roomId, 'm.room.message', content);
       |                      ^
    299|   },
    300| 
 ❯ Proxy.<anonymous> node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs:1380:30
 ❯ Proxy.mockCall node_modules/@vitest/spy/dist/index.js:50:17
 ❯ Proxy.spy node_modules/tinyspy/dist/index.js:42:80
 ❯ test/plugins/pluginVotingWidget.test.ts:26:22
 ❯ node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:128:14
 ❯ node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:59:26
 ❯ runTest node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:675:17
 ❯ runSuite node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:793:15
 ❯ runSuite node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:793:15
```

The thing I am struggling with is making vitest recognize the sendEvent() function.